# Apache Camel JMS to MySql

Tags: apache-camel

I have a requirement to write a code whenever there is a new entry in the JMS queue, I want that entry to be persisted in the MySql database.  I read that this is possible using Apache Camel project. Could any one point out to the examples or some documentation related to the same.

Lokesh

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's rather straight forward. At least the JMS and Database parts.

```
from("jms:queue:someQueue")
 .bean(SomeTransformerBean.class) // transform the message, custom code etc in 
 .to("sql:insert into FOO X VALUES(#)"); // need to enter some valid SQL statement here
```

Read more here

http://camel.apache.org/sql-component.html

and here
http://camel.apache.org/jms

Comment: Is it possible to subscribe to jms:queue:someQueue, so that whenever some one publishes to the queue I want to write the data to the database.

Comment: Yes, look at my example in the answer above.
Also, "publish" and "subscribe" is not really applicable to queues, it's terminology mostly used for "topics". Send and receive would be more appropriate.

Comment: The above example is working for me, but my camel doesnt wait for indefenitely. I want to make my Camel wait until I give shutdown.  At this moment, camel starts, waits for 5 seconds and shutsdown, how to make camel wait for indefinite.

Comment: That's a totally different question. Please spend some time and go through camel basics, tutorials etc. on the camel web page.

for your question, you will find the solution here
http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html