# How to subscribe to a topic using Camel

Tags: apache, apache-camel, ibatis

I would like to subscribe to activemq topic using camel. Can anyone share the route configuration or example for doing the same.

My requirement is whenever a new data is published on the topic I want to push the content to database using ibatis.

thanks
Lokesh

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache Camel JMS to MySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197644/apache-camel-jms-to-mysql)

Comment: I suggest you take a moment to read the Camel docs, examples, and other blogs and articles etc. Then when you got more knowledge about Camel under your belt, then you can use stackoverflow for more technical and precises questions.

Answer (score 1):

You do the normal setup of the jms component and use the following at the start of your route:

So the key is to write jms:topic: instead of jms:. This tells camel that the name after the colon is a topic name instead of a queue name. This make camel install a listener for the topic. So for every message sent to the topic your route is called.

Comment: I am presently doing in the same way as you suggested, but my camel shutsdown automatically after 5 seconds.

Comment: How do you run camel? Can you post your project somewhere?